# syntax help for comparison logic

Tags: oracle, cognos

I am trying to find out the loss of portfolios from the current month to the prior month.
What I want to see is what missing, basically when we compare the two months together I want to display what is not matching between the two
I have put this expression.

```
If([portfolio_code Current ]=[portfolio_code_Prior])
Then(Count([portfolio_code Current ])
Else(0)
```

I am not sure my if syntax is incorrect I just wanted to give an example

any insights?

[enter image description here][image: 1]

Comment: Can you show example of the data stored on the tables? and also the data you are expecting to see, to get a better vision of what kind of example we can provide

Comment: Also if you are working with sql the syntax you are looking for is 'CASE' instead of if

Comment: That's not an example of anything.  [current month portfolio] = [current month portfolio] will always be true.  Please describe the problem better and tell us what you have already tried to solve it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So, if you sum [Difference Of Portfolios Count], do you get the number you seek?

Comment: "loss of portfolios from the current month to the prior month" - You want to know how many portfolios were lost when moving backward through time?  So how many portfolios were added from last month to this month?

Comment: or "display what is not matching"?  That's not the same thing.  What are you trying to find?

Comment: Hi Dougp, what I want show is that: if current month does not equal to prior month then, show the current month else 0

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket within the Then clause,  should be:
If([portfolio_code Current ]=[portfolio_code_Prior])
Then(Count([portfolio_code Current ]))
Else(0)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is one portfolio per row the count of portfolios that were in last month and not this month is...

```
total(
  If ( [portfolio_code Current ] <> [portfolio_code_Prior] && [portfolio_code_Prior] is not null)
  Then ( 1 )
  Else ( 0 )
)
```

or

```
total(
  case
    when [portfolio_code Current ] <> [portfolio_code_Prior] and 
         [portfolio_code_Prior] is not null
      then 1
    else 0
  end
)
```

If you want to see how many were "lost" from this month to last month (how many were added form last month to this month) you would need to reverse the logic.

If you want to see how many more or less, that is much simpler:

```
count(distinct [portfolio_code_Prior]) -
count(distinct [portfolio_code Current ])
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you want 0 when they don't match otherwise the portfolio code, then your logic looks okay.
- If you want to ONLY see the rows that do not match then add a detail filter for the custom data item, let's call it compare, like this:

[Compare] <> 0

- as far as counting, you can just select the column and use count (or count distinct) depending on what you want.